# Create a shortcut in TeXstudio for $*$ and automatically move cursor to *

Tags: macros, texstudio, shortcut

Like prompt says, I want a command to allow quicker mathematical equations. I have created my own commands in the past but cant figure this out.

Ideally I would end up with a shortcut like `\m` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> that would type `$$` and then press the left arrow key.

If this cannot be done native to TeXstudio, could someone suggest a good minimalist macro program to make this work?

Comment: Autohotkey or autoit

Answer (score 4):

It's built into TeXstudio with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on MacOS). If you prefer <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, you can edit TeXstudio's shortcuts in Options > Configure TeXstudio > Shortcuts. Inline math is under the "Math" dropdown.