# Fast dollar signs

Tags: macros, inline

Is there a way to use a keyboard shortcut to obtain the dollar signs for inline math? The best I could do in TeXStudio was make a macro that entered the following upon Shift + F1

```
$   $
```

However it always puts the cursor to the right, so I have to press the left arrow key twice everytime I use inline math.

Is there a faster, (nicer way for my hands) to do this?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen, how the link is related to the question in here?

Comment: How about the dollar sign (Shift+4)? Might sound trivial, but it sure is easy enough?

Comment: does this help: [Create a shortcut in TeXstudio for $*$ and automatically move cursor to *](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347902/579)

Comment: @Marijn: To easy, most likely ;-)

Comment: why do you need a shortcut at all, I'd just type one dollar then type some math then type one dollar then you don't need to move the cursor in at the start or out at the end.

Comment: @CroCo: I gave the link with the best intensions, and its relevance is self explanatory.

Comment: I actually have my own answer now; it turns out pressing Ctrl + Shift + M does exactly what I want. Who knew!